# Existence of finitely many global secitions which generate $\mathcal{O}_X$-module of finite type

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have a question.

Let $X$ be a quasi-compact scheme.
Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a $\mathcal{O}_X$-module of finite type (locally generated by finitely many sections).
Assume that $\mathcal{F}$ is genetaed by its global sections $(s_i)_{i\in I}$.

Q. Then $\mathcal{F}$ can be generated by finitely many global sections? More concretely, is there a finite subfamily of the $(s_i)_{i\in I}$ which generates $\mathcal{F}$?

I think I prove the statement and upload for making sure.

My strategy is first using the Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, Proposition 7.29. :

**Proposition 7.29.** Let $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ be a ringed space and let $\mathcal{F}$ be an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module of finite type. Let $x\in X$ be a point and let $s_i \in  \Gamma(U, \mathcal{F})$ for $i=1, \cdots ,n$ be sections over some open neighborhood of $x$ such that the germs $(s_i)_x$ generate the stalk $\mathcal{F}_x$. Then there exists an open neighborhood $V\subset U$, such that the $s_i|_V$ generate $\mathcal{F}|_V$.

Let $x\in X$. Since $\mathcal{F}$ is of finite type, there exists an open neighborhood $x\in U_x \subseteq X$ and local sections $\{l_1, \cdots,l_{n_x} \} \subseteq \Gamma(U_x, \mathcal{F})$ which generates $\mathcal{F}|_{U_x}$.

Since $(s_{i,x})_{i\in I}$ generates $\mathcal{F}_x$ as $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$-module. we can express each $l_{j,x}$ in terms of $s_{i,x}$  's ; i.e., $$l_{1,x} = a_{1,1}s_{1,1,x}+ \cdots + a_{1,n_1}s_{1,n_1,x}, \cdots , l_{n_x,x}=a_{n_x,1}s_{n_x,1,x} + \cdots + a_{n_x,n_{n_x}}s_{n_x,n_{n_x},x}$$

for some $a_{j,k} \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$

So, $\{{s_{1,1,x}, \cdots , s_{1,n_1,x}, \cdots, s_{n_x,1,x}, \cdots , s_{n_x,n_{n_x},x}}\}$ generates $\mathcal{F}_x$.

So, by the above proposition 7.29, there exists an open neighborhood $x\in V_x \subseteq U_x$ such that $\{{s_{1,1}|_{V_{x}}, \cdots , s_{1,n_1}|_{V_{x}}, \cdots, s_{n_x,1}|_{V_{x}}, \cdots , s_{n_x,n_{n_x}}}|_{V_{x}}\}$ generates $\mathcal{F}|_{V_{x}}$.

Since $X$ is quasi-compact, thre is a finite open subcover $X = \bigcup_{1\le k \le n}V_{x_{k}}$.

We have that for each $k$, there is a finite subfamily of $(s_i)_{i\in I}$ which generates $\mathcal{F}$ over $V_{x_{k}}$. So by the union of such finite subfamily for all $k$, we can find a finite subfamily of $(s_i)_{i\in I}$ which generates $\mathcal{F}$.

Is this argument correct?

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: Yes. Thank you~~